# create multiple keys via same item

Tags: vba, ms-word, powerpoint

Good day!

I have a main loop that gets the Title of an article, It's description and it's main text. I get them by their Word style.
I  also have a function that is called at the end of the main loop. I have a dictionary in it. It does its job. Now i need to create another dictionary or alternative to it. Where I can have Key - Descripion of an article and Item - The Title of an article. Means i can have multiple keys with the same Items.

Right Now i have a problem everytime I call dictionary2.add Key:=descriptionVariable Item:=TitleOfAnArticle(titleOfTheWord) i override the existing value, and i know why. Just dont know how to get around it. Any thoughts on it?

```
For Each StyleInWord in ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
   If StyleInWord.Style = "Style of The Title" Then 
        tileOfTheWord = StyleInWord.Range 'here i store the paragraph.
   End If
   
   'The rest of the code works same as above, with its features.

   Call TheFunction
   
Next
Function Theunction(titleOfTheWord)
   'I here create a dictionary with key - The Title of The Article; Item - Item is a path to the image of that particular Title
End Function
```

Comment: Do you mean one key with multiple values?  You can put the values in an array or a collection and store that as the dictionary value.  It would help to show more of your existing code.

Comment: @TimWilliams No, i meant same item with many keys. I acually managed to do so.

Comment: By the way, Word has a built-in Style "Title." It also has a built-in Document Property "Title" which can be accessed both in vba and using the Quick Parts > Document Property menu.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to put another dictionary as global. So i would not delete and create it anew everytime i call the function.

```
Set dictionary = new Scripting.dictionary

For Each StyleInWord in ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
   If StyleInWord.Style = "Style of The Title" Then 
        tileOfTheWord = StyleInWord.Range 'here i store the paragraph.
   End If
   
   'The rest of the code works same as above, with its features.

   Call TheFunction
   
Next
Function Theunction(titleOfTheWord)
   'I here create a dictionary with key - The Title of The Article; Item - Item is a path to the image of that particular Title
End Function
```